# Read hex from file and convert to decimal

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, hex, readline

After a few weeks of reading *Learn Python The Hard Way*, I want to try to create a small program to read [text file contain hex] and write another file [as decimal]. I expect after type the command-line `python convert_hex.py hex.txt`, Python will create a new file called `hex_1.txt`.

```
#this is content from hex.txt
0x5B03FA01
0x42018360
0x9FF943B3
```

this is what I expected my python to deliver output

```
#this is content from hex_1.txt
1526987265
1107395424
2683913139
```

After 3 hour of trial and error. I can see a result in the way I want. The code is follow;

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

def hex2dec (hex):
    result_dec = int(hex, 0)
    return result_dec

script, from_file = argv

to_file = from_file[:len(from_file)-4] + "_1.txt"
out_file = open(to_file, 'w').close()

with open(from_file) as in_file:
    lines = in_file.read().splitlines()

for i in lines:
    converted = str(hex2dec (i))
    out_file = open(to_file, 'a+')
    out_file.write(converted + "\n")
    out_file.close()

    print "converted =" + str(converted)

print "done."
```

But I think there are plenty of area I should study further e.g. bug handling in hex2dec function. Could anyone suggest me what I can study further to improve this code?

Comment: [codereview.se] - but please see their tour and guidelines before posting

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One obvious problem is that `[:len(from_file)-4]` is both: 1. unnecessary (`[:-4]` would do the job); and 2. not correct, because file extensions, where even present, are not always three characters. But yes, you should post on [codereview.se].

Comment: oops. I will post at Code Review. Thank you everyone.

How do I closed this?

Comment: Keep studying algorithms and data structure.